# Efficient way to recursively find files based on a set of substrings, storing their paths

Tags: python, file, recursion, search

I struggle to come up with an efficient way of doing a recursive file search based on *n* substrings, that is able to store the full paths of the files that have been found.

Scenario: a main data folder with ~100 subfolders, each of which having another ~100 subfolders. Those sub-subfolders contain a couple of hundred .XML files each. Additionally, I have a list of about 500 unique file identifiers (i.e. 'xx1.XML', 'xx2.XML', etc.). The goal is to retrieve the full file paths of all of those, considering they can be in any folder, on any level within the main data folder.

My initial approach was to use `glob.iglob('data-folder' + '**/**', recursive=True)`, which returns a generator object with all folders and files within `data-folder` recursively. Subsequently I would loop over the generator and check which of the paths contain one of the file identifiers. However, due the vast amount of files this is not really viable time-wise. I would really appreciate to hear your input regarding this topic.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of would be to use `os.walk()`, however I doubt if it will be any faster since I suspect that either way, most of the time is being spent doing calls to some OS files & folders API.

Comment: Your code is going to be IO bound.  Put your 500 file identifiers in a set, as as your reach each file, see if its name is in the set.  Opening and listing a directory is so much slower than anything else your program is doing.